# Preventing Debug Spam in eVC4

Tags: c++, debugging, windows-ce, spam, evc4

I have an application that I need to debug on a target system.

All the relevant TRACE macros are in place to send messages to the debug window, however, I'm having difficulties in finding a way to prevent the spam there.

You see, this application is regularly creating & terminating threads, so I am getting a large amount of "The thread 0x23CF2B8A has exited with code 0 (0x0)" messages.

I've looked through the various menu options but I can't seem to find a way to disable this automated output.

Is there any way I can do this to clean up my debug window?

Comment: I forgot to add that the target environment is Windows CE 4.0

This means, unfortunately, I can't use dbgview.exe as it requires XP or better :/

Comment: Is there an option that disables the Window somewhere? :|

Comment: I don't want to disable the TRACE window, as I want to see the messages that 'I' create. I just want to get rid of the messages that the IDE is creating.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could do with a [worker thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) or a fixed number of threads.

Should you go with a fixed number of threads, you will also gain performance, i.e. when using as many threads as CPUs.

Another argument for *not* creating large amounts of threads on the fly is backward-compatibility. Windows used to leak resources (on XP SP1, if I remember correctly) when creating/destroying threads, so that the process eventually could not ::CreateThread(). (Hopefully this is fixed by now, but don't count on it.)

Comment: No, the design is already implemented, and as such would take too long to change now. I have to deal with what was written, and need a way to see the TRACE output without the IDE spam messages.